# How to make custom order and largest to smallest in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

My data is

```
id       name
----------------
1      L_one
2      z_odin
3      e_lock
4      b_block
5      L_joke
```

**I want to make my order like this**

```
id       name
------------------
5      L_joke
1      L_one
4      b_block
3      e_block
2      z_odin
```

First, I want to orderby named begin with "L". Second, I want to order id largest to smallest.
**How can I code in this case?**
*Thank All*

I had tried this problem.
In real, my problem is a little complicate. So, I asked very simple solution to clear my question.

---

**Edited**

I tried code are here

```
Product::where('state','<>','banned')->where('created_at','LIKE',$today.'%')
    ->union(Product::orderBy('view', 'DESC'))->take(80)->get();
```

```
Product::orderBy(DB::raw('FIELD(created_at, "2021-01-18 ++")'),'DESC')->orderBy('view','desc')->get();
```

```
Product::whereDate('created_at', now())->orderBy('view','desc')->get();
```

I also read laravel docs.
I also search similar question.
But northing to solve for my problems.

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. we help you with YOUR code, we will not write it for you. At least give it a try. Begin by reading the docs of Laravel...

Comment: @GertB. I tried about five day but I can't.
This is simple question. In real, I tried code is `Product::orderBy(DB::raw('FIELD(created_at, "2021-01-18 ++")'),'DESC')->orderBy('view','desc')->get();`

and then `Product::where('state','<>','banned')->where('created_at','LIKE',$today.'%')
    ->union(Product::orderBy('view', 'DESC'))->take(80)->get();`

Comment: @MraukOoDeveloper then show us what you tried... add your code...

Comment: @GertB. My  real code is a little complicate to ask. So, I asked very simple question. _thank for your sugges.

Comment: You don't need to post your actual code if it's private, but at least post what have you tried so far, like the code you just posted in a comment above - edit the question and put it in the question body - show that you've made some effort and people will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

```
$answer = Model::orderByRaw('SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1)="L" desc, id desc')->get();
```